# Why day in sysdate not working for monday in plsql trigger?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

```
create or replace trigger trig1
before delete or insert or update on students 
begin
if( To_char(sysdate,'day') = 'monday' then
raise_application_error(-20500,'table is secured');
end if;
end;
```

I create trigger but it is not working for `monday` and it performs DML actions on table. I found one solution - to use dy instead of day - but why?

Comment: Syntax error. Different number of "(" and ")".

Comment: Perhaps internationalization settings.

Answer (score 4):

There are two reasons.

When you use `day` then result is padded with blanks to longest name, try

```
SELECT '"'||To_char(sysdate, 'day')||'"'
FROM dual;

"monday   "
```

Use `'fmday'` to avoid this.

Then result of `TO_CHAR()` depends on current user session `NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE` settings. Use

```
To_char(sysdate, 'fmday', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = american') = 'monday'`
```

in order to be independent from settings of current user session.

Answer (score 3):

[Wernfried Domscheit has answered "why"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46404377/1509264) your query is not working (`TO_CHAR( datevalue, 'DAY' )` is right-padded with spaces).

Rather than relying on `NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE` and `NLS_TERRITORY` settings that may break if the query is used internationally, you can truncate the date and compare it to the start of the ISO-week (which is always Monday) which is independent of those settings:

```
create or replace trigger trig1
before delete or insert or update on students 
begin
  IF TRUNC( SYSDATE ) = TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'IW' ) THEN
    raise_application_error(-20500,'table is secured');
  END IF;
end;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can work with the day numbers instead:

```
create or replace trigger trig1
before delete or insert or update on students 
begin
if( To_char(sysdate,'d') = '2' then
raise_application_error(-20500,'table is secured');
end if;
end;
```

Documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00210

> D - Day of week (1-7). This element depends on the NLS territory of the session.